# Outer product of row vectors. Does $\mathbf{x}^T \otimes \mathbf{y}^T$ = $\mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{y}$?

Tags: outer-product

Does $\mathbf{x}^T \otimes \mathbf{y}^T$ = $\mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{y}$?

Comment: If $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are row vectors, is the outer product defined for $\mathbf{x}\otimes \mathbf{y}$? Also you should define what everything in the question means, without relying on the title or tags.

Answer (score 2):

Without making matrix identifications, if $x,y\in V$, then $x^\top,y^\top\in V^*$. Thus, $x\otimes y\in V\otimes V$ and $x^\top\otimes y^\top\in V^*\otimes V^*$. Although both of these can be identified with $V\otimes V^*\cong \text{Hom}(V,V)$ once you choose a basis and dual basis, these are very different entities.

Answer (score 1):

The *outer* product is equivalent to the standard matrix product if we interpret (column) vectors as $n \times 1$ matrices:
$$
\mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} \, \mathbf{y}^\top. 
$$
You can see by looking at dimensions that this makes sense. In order for matrix multiplication to be defined the column count on the left must match the row count on the right, and here we have
$$
(n \times 1)(1 \times n) = (n \times n).
$$

On the other hand, $\mathbf{x}^\top \otimes \mathbf{y}^\top$ doesn't make sense as an outer product, as $\mathbf{x}^\top$ and $\mathbf{y}^\top$ are row vectors (often interpreted as *co*vectors in many contexts). If we just go ahead and blindly compute
$$
\mathbf{x}^\top \otimes \mathbf{y}^\top 
= \mathbf{x}^\top (\mathbf{y}^\top)^\top 
= \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{y}, 
$$
what we have is a row vector multiplied by a column vector, which yields a scalar since
$$
(1 \times n)(n \times 1) = (1 \times 1).
$$
This is called the *inner* product of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But I'm surprised that it's not a famous identity. And isn't the outer product of two row vectors a (0,2)-tensor rather than a scalar?  I thought it was impossible to get a scalar from an outer product. Also, x and y could be of different lengths, but an inner product can only be between vectors of equal length.

Comment: @TomekDobrzynski You can only multiply two matrices of size $a\times b$ and $c\times d$ if $b=c$.